SAS ODS text margins wider than table in PROC REPORT
I'm modifying an existing SAS program provided by our grant funder to automatically create RTF report tables with styles that match what our reports looked like in the past. I'm encountering two problems:

margins for the ODS text are wider than the table itself creating problems for pasting into a document
the existing reports have no horizontal gridlines but do have vertical gridlines that should be color bed3d7

I've spent hours trying to fix the two issues.  I'm using Enterprise Guide 8.2 Update 5. Here is the code (note that because I have several similar tables I set up a macro for the purpose of easy formatting)

%let out = ;

data demo1;
    length characteristic $30 clevel $50;
    input characteristic $ clevel $ cfrequency crowpercent Lower_CI Upper_CI;
    datalines;
Race/Ethnicity Asian 7 3.5 0.9 6.2
Race/Ethnicity Black 25 12.3 7.6 16.9
Race/Ethnicity Latinx 92 41.2 34.5 47.8
Race/Ethnicity NHPI 5 0.7 0.0 2.0
Race/Ethnicity White 100 37.9 31.5 44.3
Race/Ethnicity Multiple 9 4.5 1.5 7.5
Age 18-24 5 1.9 0.0 3.7
Age 25-34 28 11.6 7.3 15.8
Age 35-44 41 19.3 13.8 24.8
Age 45-54 58 26.2 20.1 32.2
Age >=55 103 41.1 34.6 47.7
;
run;

data demo2 (drop=Lower_CI Upper_CI);
set demo1;
CI=catx('-', put(Lower_CI, 4.1), put(Upper_CI, 4.1));
run;

%macro outtable1 (tableno=, columnwidth=, headerheight=, cellheight=, clevelwidth=, cfrequencywidth=, 
                crowwidth=, CIwidth=, spanhead=);

goptions device=emf;
title;
options nodate orientation=portrait nonumber;
ods escapechar='^';
ods rtf file = "&out\&tableno..rtf";

proc report split='*' nowindows data=&tableno nowindows style(column)={asis=on}
style(report)={LEFTMARGIN=0.5in font_face="arial" font_size=14pt color=black rules=none BACKGROUND=_undef_ frame=hsides
               background=cxe8efef borderwidth = .01in posttext=" "}
style(column)={just=left font_face="arial" cellspacing = 0 font_size=12pt  
               cellwidth=&columnwidth rules=none background=white}
style(header)={just=left vjust=center font_face="arial" font_weight=bold font_size=12pt color=white
               cellheight=&headerheight font_size=12pt rules=rows 
               frame=hsides background=cx007077 paddingleft=0.15in}
style(lines) ={background=cxf0f5f5};

column ("%bquote(&spanhead)" (characteristic clevel cfrequency crowpercent CI));

define characteristic / order noprint order=data width=60 flow; 
define clevel         / display '' CENTER order=internal
                        style(column)={cellwidth=&clevelwidth just=left paddingleft=0.2in}
                        style(header)={cellheight=&cellheight cellwidth=&clevelwidth just=left background=cxbed3d7 color=black};
define cfrequency     / 'Number^{super a}' CENTER 
                        style(column)={cellwidth=&cfrequencywidth just=CENTER}
                        style(header)={cellheight=&cellheight cellwidth=&cfrequencywidth just=CENTER background=cxbed3d7 color=black};
define crowpercent    /'Percentage^{super b}' CENTER 
                        style(column)={cellwidth=&crowwidth just=CENTER}
                        style(header)={cellheight=&cellheight cellwidth=&crowwidth just=CENTER background=cxbed3d7 color=black};
define CI             / '95% CI^{super c}' CENTER WIDTH=25
                        style(column)={cellwidth=&CIwidth just=CENTER}
                        style(header)={cellheight=&cellheight cellwidth=&CIwidth just=CENTER background=cxbed3d7 color=black};
compute before characteristic / style = [font_weight=bold font_size=12pt font_face="arial" font_style=italic paddingleft=0.2in]; 
line @1 characteristic $195. ; 
endcomp;
COMPUTE clevel;
IF clevel= 'Total' THEN CALL DEFINE(_ROW_, "style", "STYLE=[font_weight=bold background=cxbed3d7]");
ENDCOMP;
run;

%mend;

%include "&path.\outtable1.sas";

%outtable1(tableno=demo2, columnwidth=0.6in, headerheight=0.3in, cellheight=0.3in, clevelwidth=3.2in, 
            cfrequencywidth=1.3in, crowwidth=1.3in, CIwidth=1.3in, spanhead=%str(3.1. Demographics, 2022));

ODS TEXT='^S={LEFTMARGIN=0.5in RIGHTMARGIN=0.5in fontsize=9pt font_face="arial"}';
ODS TEXT='^S={LEFTMARGIN=0.5in RIGHTMARGIN=0.5in fontsize=9pt font_face="arial"}Abbreviations: CI, confidence interval; [footnotes only].';
ODS TEXT='^S={LEFTMARGIN=0.5in RIGHTMARGIN=0.5in fontsize=9pt font_face="arial"}^{style[font_style=italic]Note}. Numbers might not add to total because of “don’t know”
 and skipped (missing) responses. Percentages might not sum to 100 because of rounding. Estimates with a denominator sample size of <30, an absolute CI width ^{Unicode 2265}30, estimates with an absolute CI width
 between 5 and 30 and a relative CI width >130%, and estimates of 0% or 100% are marked with an asterisk (*) and should be interpreted with caution.' ;
ODS TEXT='^S={LEFTMARGIN=0.5in RIGHTMARGIN=0.5in fontsize=9pt font_face="arial"}^{super a} Numbers are unweighted.';
ODS TEXT='^S={LEFTMARGIN=0.5in RIGHTMARGIN=0.5in fontsize=9pt font_face="arial"}^{super b} Percentages are weighted percentages.';
ODS TEXT='^S={LEFTMARGIN=0.5in RIGHTMARGIN=0.5in fontsize=9pt font_face="arial"}^{super c} CIs incorporate weighted percentages.';
ODS TEXT='^S={LEFTMARGIN=0.5in RIGHTMARGIN=0.5in fontsize=9pt font_face="arial"}^{super d} Hispanics or Latinos can be of any race. Persons are classified in only one
race/ethnicity category.';

The photo sample table shows how if the entire table is selected, the footnotes (created with ODS text) have wider margins than the table.
This is a relatively simple table that is one of over 20 tables I'm updating.  Any help would be appreciated.

Version of EG (tool you used to submit the SAS code) should not matter for how RTF output is generated.  The more important version to know is which version of SAS is the server you are connecting to with EG running?  Check the automatic macro variable &SYSVLONG.

SAS 9.4M6 64 bit version

Can you provide a small example (including data, perhaps using one of the SASHELP datasets) that demonstrates the issue?  It will be hard for anyone to experiment if they cannot run the program.  Also does it matter what software you use to render the RTF file?  How are you looking at the RTF file?  Do you open it in WORD? Or something else?

Original post updated to create sample table. Please excuse the minor edits I made to the table content to simplify things. You'll want to set up a macro variable &out for the output location. Thanks for any help you can provide.

As mentioned in the documentation:

The UserText style element controls text specified with the TEXT= statement.

The relevant style attribute is width (aliases cellwidth and outputwidth). You should also center the output on the page as is done for the table. Both can be set by modifying or creating a style using PROC TEMPLATE. I'm not sure which style you're using or even which one is the default (looks like it differs in EG), but this code should more or less do what you need -- in my case a width of 90% aligns both elements quite well:
ods path work.template(update) sashelp.tmplmst;
proc template;
   define style styles.myrtf;
      parent=styles.rtf;
      style usertext from usertext / just=c width=90%;
   end;
run;

You'll then have to invoke this style in ODS RTF and left-justify the actual contents of ODS TEXT (only relevant pieces shown):
ods rtf style=myrtf file=...;
/* [.. PROC REPORT ..] */

ods text='^S={just=l ...}';
/* [.. more ODS TEXT ..] */
ods rtf close;

It's a bit less clear what exactly you expect for your second issue, this can probably be done using a rules=cols style attribute.

This works perfectly, thank you!
